# Problema de compatibilidad en MinGW: No ejecuta un archivo en 64 bits

Tags: c

A través de MinGW estoy compilando y ejecutando un archivo escrito en C.

Una vez que tengo el archivo escrito (main.h), lo compilo en el programa: main.exe

```
gcc main.h -o main.exe
```

El problema es que una vez tengo el archivo compilado y deseo ejecutarlo en MinGW, me aparece el siguiente mensaje en una ventana:

> El programa o característica "\Ruta del archivo\" no se puede iniciar
>   o ejecutar porque no es compatible con versiones de 64 bits de
>   Windows. Consulte con el fabricante de software si existe una versión
>   disponible que sea compatible con Windows de 64 bits.

Además en el símbolo de sistema me aparece este mensaje que indica lo mismo.

> Esta versión de "\Ruta del archivo\" no es compatible con la versión
>   de Windows que está ejecutando. Compruebe la información de sistema
>   del equipo y después póngase en contacto con el anunciante de
>   software.

¿Cómo puedo ejecutarlo correctamente o compilarlo en 64 bits?

Muchas gracias para quienes responden mi pregunta

Comment: veo que la extension de tu archivo **main.h** , por lo que estas indicando que es una cabecera de programa, por lo cual puede que te este dando algún error al quererlo convertir en un **main.exe** que por lo regular las cabeceras no son archivos ejecutables; las extensiones mas comunes para compilar y tener como resultado un ejecutable son **.c** y **.cpp** .

Comment: @Krasnax C no entiende de extensiones. Somos los programadores los que, para no complicarnos en exceso, usamos ciertas convenciones, como intentar dejar en los `.c` la implementación y en los `.h` la declaración de funciones... pero es perfectamente *legal* tener todo el código en un `.h`... e incluso podría ser un `.porquemedalagana` o en un archivo sin extensión. Eso no va a afectar en nada al código binario final

Comment: En cuanto a la pregunta... MinGW es un **compilador**... solo sirve para compilar programas, no para ejecutarlos. ¿Cómo ejecutas el programa en MinGW exactamente?

Comment: @eferion C no entiende de *extensiones* ... pero el compilador **si**. `gcc -o main main.h`, en mi Linux, genera una `GCC precompiled header (version 014) for C`. Para esas cosas, está la opción `-x lang` del gcc. **No se** si el `mingw` en Windows actua igual, pero lo veo posible y probable.

Comment: @Krasnax Muchas gracias, lo he intentado compilando con **.c** y el archivo ejecutado funciona. Noté que la miniatura del programa cambió y el detalle del archivo también "C Header File" a "C Source File". Gracias.

Comment: @eferion Claro que tienes razón, en todo lo que dijiste, pero a veces no todos los programadores son muy **experimentados**, y es bueno conocer y llevar buenas prácticas a la hora de desarrollar algún programa, incluso si se esta aprendiendo; **MinGW** algunas veces da uno que otro dolor de cabeza, pero en fin me alegra que funcione.